# The leader of our clan kicked us and left the clan

Tags: clash-of-clans

Our leader just kicked us out of our clan, and he eventually left. There are no members left in our clan and it is set to be closed. What can I do to recover our clan if I'm just an elder?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your clan is lost. If you wish, you could start a new clan with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't think that you have many options. You can try to contact the developers and try to get them to set you back into the clan. But I would bet, they won't do.

Instead you can create a new clan and invite your old fellows and start over again.

Answer (score 0):

As the leader,you can't do anything about it.You have two options: Message SuperCell and ask them to give you the clan back,or join/create your own clan.